# mdbootstrap with angular - animations not working

Tags: angular, material-design, mdbootstrap

I have followed the guide here: https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Angular-Bootstrap-with-Material-Design. And things look how I would expect, but animations does not work. On this demo page: https://mdbootstrap.com/components/buttons/ Buttons have a wave effect when clicked, but when I copy/past the demo code into my (test) app.component.html, then there is no wave effect.

It seems that some event handlers are not registered, but Im not sure how to make this happen...

**Edit**

After some more poking around, I actually found out how to make ripples work! :)
Here is my app.module.ts (The RippleModule import is important):

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { RippleModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md/ripple';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    RippleModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Example of how to use ripples on a button:

```
<!-- mdbRippleRadius attribute (directive) and the waves-light class is imporant -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-light" mdbRippleRadius >Primary</button>
```

Comment: Carousel does also not work. So Im missing some js I think, but not sure what!

Comment: This is slightly unrelated, but as I've made more and more projects with Angular I've actually found that using @angular/flex-layout is a far better solution than bootstrap with angular projects with flex boxes. It may be out of scope of what you're doing, but wanted to let you know it existed.

Comment: I agree, there is no longer a really good reason to use bootstrap if it is only for the grid-layout system. But mdboostrap has a loot more than that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the directive `mdbRippleRadius` to your html if you are using Angular.io.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" mdbRippleRadius>Primary</button>
```

See the Angular Bootstrap with Material Design:

[https://mdbootstrap.com/**angular**/components/buttons/](https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/components/buttons/)